# How to Trigger Firestore function on Creation of Sub Document in a sub Collection

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a collection called pledges and inside it I have a field called pay to which is a collection that holders other subdocuments.
I am writing a function to listen and get the newly created data in the sub-collection but I am not getting it right. My target is to get the id and the new doc and its data.

```
exports.createPayers = 
 functions.firestore.document("/pledges/{id}/payto/{payDocID}").onCreate(async (snap, context) 
  => {
  console.log("This is working");
  // get payer doc id
  const payerDocID = snap.id;

  // Get the payer Doc Data
  const payerDocData = snap.data().amountToPay;

  console.log(payerDocID.amountToPay + "is the pay id");
  return null;
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// get payer doc id
const payerDocID = snap.id;

// Get the payer Doc Data
const payerDocData = snap.data().amountToPay;

console.log(payerDocID.amountToPay + "is the pay id");
```

`payerDocID` is a string (ID of new document created) and `payerDocData` is actually the value of amount to pay (number). You are trying to access the property `amountToPay` on a string which will log `undefined is the pay id`.

Try refactoring your code like this:

```js
const payerDocID = snap.id

const payerDocData = snap.data() // no .amountToPay here

console.log(`PayerDocID: ${payerDocId}`)
console.log(`Amount to pay: ${payerDocData.amountToPay}`)
```

```
/pledges/{id}/payto/{payDocID}
```

If you need the parameters in wildcards i.e. `id` and `payDocID`, you can use `context` object:

```js
const {id, payDocID} = context.params
console.log(id, payDocID)
```